# Ошибка импорта при обновлении бота с aiogram2 до aiogram3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x, aiogram-2.x

переписываю бота с aiogram2 на 3, проблема с import. from aiogram.utils.markdown import escape_md as escape

Вот такую ошибку выдаёт терминал:

```
in <module>
    from aiogram.utils.markdown import escape_md as escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape_md' from 'aiogram.utils.markdown'
```

Вот импорты:

```
import logging
from qiwi_api import Qiwi
import asyncio
import datetime
import random, string
from copy import deepcopy
import time
import math
import requests, threading
import crypto
import sql
import game
import key_board
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.client.bot import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils.markdown import escape_md as escape
```